# How to get the user information through the user name?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to send messages to people out of a discord guild. The reason behind this was because this guild got hacked and many members were kicked. A solution that I was thinking was: getting every user kicked from the audit log into a json, read this json and use the user names to get their information as a `<class 'discord.user.User'>`, then I could use this datatype to send them a message to bring them back (user_info.send(msg)).

For this reason, I was wondering is if possible to get the user information as a `<class 'discord.user.User'>` using the user name (`Mycustomname#1234`).

Will be something like:

```py
@bot.commands(name=user_info)
async def get_user_info(ctx, user_name, msg):
    ...
   await user_class.send(msg)

# Input/output of the user
input: Mycustomname#1234
output: <User id=113112246122784145 name='Mycustomname' discriminator='1234' bot=False>
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the json you want to retrieve the info from? Dummy data will do.

Comment: Firstly, your bot needs to share a server with the user you are trying to send DMs to so what you are about to try won't work and instead raise `discord.Forbidden 403` error. Secondly, you are looking for this 
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.audit_logs

Comment: @schilli the sample data is already added

Comment: @MysteryR , but should be a way using my user token, since I can send message to someone who is not my friend and we are not sharing servers, but I had the user name

Comment: @Y4RD13 it's not, even you shouldn't be able to dm users that don't share a mutual server with you (you can only if you are friends with them)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with `discord.utils`

```
user = discord.utils.get(bot.users, name="Mycustomname", discriminator="1234")
```

or

```
user = discord.utils.find(lambda u: str(u) == "Mucustomname#1234", bot.users)
```

Comment: When Im trying to print the type and the output of `user ` I get: `<class 'NoneType'>
None`

Comment: If your bot and that user haven't a mutual guild, it returns NoneType.

Comment: In your case if you want to fetch the discord.User object, I would recommend using fetch_user (an API call) however it can only be used by bot accounts which is mentioned in the discord.py docs

Comment: @Weylyn we are sharing guild and is returning `None`